# Copy specific properties using spring BeanUtils

Tags: java, spring

I have a model class which has around 45 properties. I have created another DTO class which has exactly the same properties.

At runtime, some requirements dont need me to show all the properties to the user. Hence i want to copy some properties from my model class to my DTO class and then send that object to the client.

I am using Spring.s BeanUtils.copyproperties. But here  i only see the option to ignore properties which i dont want. as the my list of unwanted properties is long, is there a way in which i can specify only the list i want.

I searched on the net and found a solution

"org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties(Object source, Object target, Class editable) throws BeansException

Ensure the target implements the interface editable which defines the properties which would be copied."

But i am not able to work my head around this editable interface. I tried using an interface which has all the properties I want and tried to use it here, but it gave me an error saying that it is expecting a class.  Can some body help me with the editable interface stuff

Answer (score 0):

I think creating another DTO with just the properties you wanted will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating copies of the object containing only a few properties, you could define various Interfaces that provide only the getter methods to the properties that you want to expose to the consumer of your object. Your DTO can implement all the different interfaces. And you hand over the interface to the consumer instead of a concrete class.

```
public class MyDTO implements Fooable, Barable {
  private String foo;
  private String bar;
  public String getFoo() {
    return foo;
  }
  public String getBar() {
    return bar;
  }
}
public interface Fooable {
  String getFoo();
}
public interface Barable {
  String getBar();
}
```